# Custom ListView - How to set attrs.xml as a namespace

Tags: android

I follow [this](http://proandroiddev.blogspot.no/2012/01/android-design-tip-drop-shadows-on.html) guide to make a custom `ListView` for my app. The tutorial uses a namespace called ottasee, which should be defined as a xml-namespace inside the element. So here is some of my code:

```
 <com.my.app.Layout.CustomListView
            xmlns:ottasee="what_should_i_put_here?"
            android:id="@+id/lastCases"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            ottasee:dropShadowBottom="true"
            ottasee:dropshadowrightsrc="@drawable/drop_shadow"
            />
```

I can see that the attributes `ottasee:dropShadowBottom` and `ottasee:dropshadowrightsrc` are part of my `attrs.xml` in the values folder. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
 <declare-styleable name="DropShadowListView">
     <attr format="boolean" name="dropShadowLeft"></attr>
     <attr format="reference" name="dropShadowLeftSrc"></attr>
     <attr format="boolean" name="dropShadowRight"></attr>
     <attr format="reference" name="dropShadowRightSrc"></attr>
     <attr format="boolean" name="dropShadowTop"></attr>
     <attr format="reference" name="dropShadowTopSrc"></attr>
     <attr format="boolean" name="dropShadowBottom"></attr>
     <attr format="reference" name="dropShadowBottomSrc"></attr>
 </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

How should I define the xml namespace for the `ListView` in order to grab the attributes from the `attrs.xml` file?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My CustomListView is under the package `com.my.app.Layout` and I tried to declare the ns this way: `xmlns:ottasee="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.app.Layout`

But I only get an error in my xml file:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'dropShadowBottom' in package 
     'com.my.app.Layout'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'dropshadowrightsrc' in package 
     'com.my.app.Layout'
```

How can I accomplish setting the right ns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following the following to include the necessary attributes to your namespace:
`xmlns:ottasee ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Slightly different to @budius's answer as it will auto-resolve the package name for you.

Answer (score 1):

usually the XML editor do it for you, I've even never worried, but it's like that:

```
xmlns:ottasee="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.package.name"
```